# Redirect not - logged in users to custom login page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm currently building my own website using wordpress.
I designed my own login - page and want users to be redirected to that page if they are not logged in.

There are several solutions to this problem, however, none of them seem to work.

I tried:

1. Adding code to the `functions.php`, such as:

```
<?php

function admin_redirect() {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

        wp_redirect( home_url( '/{custom page goes here}/' ) );

        exit;

    }

}

add_action( 'get_header', 'admin_redirect' );
```

It apparently didn't work - I also tried some other code like (to my `header.php`):

```
<?php

if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    
    wp_redirect('http://somepagehere');

    exit;

}
```

2. Use of plugins - I tried using "Force Login" and "WPS Hide Login".

First of all, installing "Force Login" didn't work when accessing the main page and only prohibited access when adding a slug to the main page (ex.: oho.nachhilfe.de/xyz). It also didn't redirect to the login page, but instead simply redirected to a 404 page (no matter what my login URL was).

Changing my login URL to a custom one using "WPS Hide Login" also didn't work, as this only replaced my custom login page with the default wordpress login page, therefore, my custom page simply got overwritten with the wordpress one.

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

Comment: You have two distinct problems to keep separate: 1) require all users to be logged in and 2) use a custom login page. I’d honestly start with [this plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/182534/12496) which seems to do both. When customizing the login page, make sure to mimic everything that WordPress does. Also, in all honesty I usually find it easier to tweak the existing login page than build my own. It is more forward compatible and plays better with some (arguably poorer built) common plugins.

Comment: @ChrisHaas The code you provided in the link actually worked in the combination with the plugin...as I said, It previously didn't work and I'm glad it does now.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's all agree that the login customization handling in WordPress is awful.

Like Chris said, forward compatibility and messing with core don't go well together.

If it's just a permalink question you can always customize them instead of re-creating the whole login system.

Moving on. Both of your spinets are perfectly working, tho `get_header` is the wrong hook to use. Redirects needs to happen before determining which template to load. which is happening before `get_header` but after `init` and `wp`.

You can use, [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) do do just that.

> Fires before determining which template to load.

```
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', function () {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page( 'login' ) ) {
    
        wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/login/' ) );

        exit;

    };

} );
```

You can refer to the [WP Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to have a better understanding of the hook firing sequence.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!

The provided code worked, but after I couldn't access my website as there was an error occurring stating that there are "too many redirects"...it kept appearing even after clearing my cache and cookies.

Fortunately Chris solutions worked too.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the action `login_init` to achieve this:

```
function my_logged_in_redirect() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        wp_safe_redirect('your address');
    }
}
add_action('login_init', 'my_logged_in_redirect');
```